# Compare an associative array where array2 has additional keys

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a fast way to compare two arrays, where the second array contains all the keys from the first, but also has additional keys?

For example, given the two arrays below, I would want the final two elements from the first array as they do not exist on the second:

```
$input = [
    [
        'firstName' => 'Paula',
        'lastName' => 'Fisher',
        'companyName' => 'Ankunding-Braun'
    ],
    [
        'firstName' => 'Elliot',
        'lastName' => 'Roob',
        'companyName' => 'Feeney PLC'
    ],
    [
        'firstName' => 'Jammie',
        'lastName' => 'Morar',
        'companyName' => 'Pollich PLC'
    ],
    [
        'firstName' => 'Tyrell',
        'lastName' => 'Mills',
        'companyName' => 'Oberbrunner, Kulas and Rice'
    ],
    [
        'firstName' => 'Fred',
        'lastName' => 'Johnson',
        'companyName' => 'Pollich PLC'
    ],
    [
        'firstName' => 'Tyrell',
        'lastName' => 'Bloggs',
        'companyName' => 'BBC East'
    ],
];

$output = [
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "firstName" => "Paula",
        "lastName" => "Fisher",
        "salutation" => "Prof.",
        "email" => "jane.fritsch@gutmann.com",
        "phone" => "1-887-271-5742 x394",
        "mobileNumber" => "1-558-612-4089 x45355"
    ],
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "firstName" => "Elliot",
        "lastName" => "Roob",
        "salutation" => "Prof.",
        "email" => "reinger.keenan@hyatt.com",
        "phone" => "+1-378-385-3633",
        "mobileNumber" => "1-815-769-2297",
    ],
    [
        "id" => 3,
        "firstName" => "Jammie",
        "lastName" => "Morar",
        "salutation" => "Mr.",
        "email"=> "amir95@becker.com",
        "phone" => "(694) 767-1593 x5966",
        "mobileNumber" => "204-991-3292",
    ],
    [
        "id" => 4,
        "firstName" => "Tyrell",
        "lastName" => "Mills",
        "salutation"=> "Mrs.",
        "email" => "crist.rick@cronin.biz",
        "phone" => "462-385-0569 x22876",
        "mobileNumber" => "532-369-9039"
    ]
];
```

As a little bit of context, I am trying to return all records that do not exist on the database (checking first name, last name and company name). If there's a faster way of doing this using the database that would be great, but I can't think of anything myself, so I've returned the records that are found, and now want to remove the found records from the searched array - therefore leaving me with the records that do not exist.

Comment: Are the keys (columns) you're looking to compare always the same? Do that in the query. What do the other fields have to do with it unless it's arbitrary which columns to compare?

Comment: Because I need the full contact model as I'll be doing something else with them. Basically, I want to enter a load of first names, last names, and company names, and then do something with the records that were found, and list the records that weren't found. I'm using Lumen and Doctrine2

Comment: What do they have to do with the filtering? That's what you're asking. You ignore them, unless I'm missing something. You also don't have `companyName` as a field in the `$output`, so it seems like it can't be compared for that column on filter given what's provided. I'm writing an answer, bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the searches not found in the results, you can:

```
// I can't "query", this is for demonstration based on the question data.
// The assumption here is that this is a hydrated to array resultset from a
// Doctrine ORM query, but it should work for any array comparison of this 
// sort.
$filtered = array_filter($output, function($row) use($input) {
    return array_reduce($input, function($carry, $compare) use($row) {
        return $carry || (
            $compare['firstName'] == $row['firstName']
            && $compare['lastName'] == $row['lastName']
            // Uncomment this if you want, and have, companyName to compare.
            // && $compare['companyName'] == $row['companyName']
        );
    });
});

$notfound = array_filter($input, function($search) use($filtered) {
    // Note the negation here, this uses array_reduce() to tell us when
    // there's a "hit", we're looking for $search rows with no "hit".
    return !array_reduce($filtered, function($carry, $row) use($search) {
        return $carry || (
            $search['firstName'] == $row['firstName']
            && $search['lastName'] == $row['lastName']
            // Uncomment this if you want, and have, companyName to compare.
            // Note that the hydrated resultset needs to account for this.
            // && $compare['companyName'] == $row['companyName']
        );
    });
});
```

https://3v4l.org/Rck9V

Comment: The company name is an important predicate as that's part of the search. For example, I'd want to check if Fred Johnson who works at the BBC exists of the database. So I check to see whether there is a record with the first name of Fred, last name of Johnson, then join the company and check the company name is BBC. If that particular record doesn't exist, I want to do something with it, so I need to know what I searched for that returned null/nothing. The company name isn't in the second array because it's hydrated by Doctrine as it's an entity relationship, not a column definition.

Comment: Then add it. You simply didn't take account of it in your `$output` array, so I didn't either. It's another check in the `array_reduce()` return condition. If you're using Doctrine ORM, you really should use DQL for that (which I'm not much of an expert on). To use arrays, you would need to hydrate it in such a way that your source to filter on has it somewhere.

Comment: I am using DQL, for the query, but there doesn't appear to be a way of saying 'create an array of the queries that returned nothing'. Thanks anyway

Comment: Create an array of the queries that return nothing? What are you talking about?

Comment: This is what it sounds like you're proposing: Pull every entity of that type that corresponds to the `$output` (I'm guessing they're not users?). Then, based on a list of people and company names, filter the whole (manually hydrated) list down to the corresponding entries (cast to an array, not an object) that match all three conditions. You can do that with a query (the answer shows how to do that, the `company` part in DQL I'm not sure about though), but the basics of what you're proposing are in the answer.

Comment: Oh wait, are you trying to find the searches not found in the master list?

Comment: Like this? https://3v4l.org/Rck9V (I'm still ignoring `companyName` because I'm lazy, but the results are the same due to the data provided.)

Comment: Say I submitted this: 
`SELECT c0_.id AS id_0, c0_.first_name AS first_name_1, c0_.last_name AS last_name_2, c0_.company_id AS company_id_7, c0_.field FROM contacts c0_ INNER JOIN companies c1_ ON c0_.company_id = c1_.id WHERE (c0_.first_name = 'Fred' AND c0_.last_name = 'Johnson' AND c1_.name = 'BBC')`. That would return all records where the first name is fred, last name johnson, and company name is BBC. If the record for Joe Bloggs did not exist, I want to be able to print out 'Fred Johnson not found on database'. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, see my comment right above. You would probably not be able to do that inversion with DQL, but that's fine because your array filter is only looking at the subset of records you actually have returned.

Comment: Just saw your comment. That's exactly what I want - provided I can get DQL to hydrate with the company name attached. Can you edit your answer so I can mark as correct?

Comment: I did just now. I would recommend editing the question to be something along the lines of _Find search queries not found in query results_ or something. The question as it stands is confusing and more prescriptive than descriptive.

Comment: Be especially careful in the manner the `companyName` is being compared. Make sure that the comparison checker operates in the same manner as the way DQL is comparing. so if it looks up a GUID from the name, make sure the `companyName` will compare it to the company name in the company entity. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I modified the `array_reduce` to check the company entities name property as follows:

`return !array_reduce($filtered, function($carry, Contact $row) use($search) {
        return $carry || (
            $search['firstName'] == $row->getFirstName()
            && $search['lastName'] == $row->getLastName()
            && $search['companyName'] == $row->getCompanyName()
        );
    });`

This works perfectly.